# Custom Flask-Admin form with some select field choices set according to another select field

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I am trying to use Flask-Admin to create a create/edit form for the model *Matriline* shown below. This model has a string field *name* and a field *pod_id* with a foreign key constraint to another model *Pod*, which itself has a foreign key field to a *Clan* model.

The default form created by Flask-Admin shows the *name* field and a select field for the *Pod* instances, but I would like to add a field *Clan*, which would reset the *Pod* list according to the *Clan* instance selected.

To add the *Clan* field I override the default ModelView for *Matriline* and add an extra select field *Clan* with all the Clan instances, as shown in the view MatrilineView below.

Now I need to add some Ajax code to the rendered form to reset the list of pods every time a new clan is selected.

Do I have to replace entirely the default form by a custom one including the Ajax code? Or is there any easier way to that with Flask-Admin?

```
<b>models.py</b>

...

class Matriline(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'matriline'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(64))
    pod_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('pod.id'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Pod(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pod'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(64))
    matrilines = db.relationship('Matriline', backref='pod', lazy='select')
    clan_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('clan.id'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Clan(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'clan'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(64))
    pods = db.relationship('Pod', backref='clan', lazy='select')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

...

<b>views.py</b>

from flask_admin.contrib import sqla
from wtforms import SelectField
from orcall import models


class MatrilineView(sqla.ModelView):
    column_hide_backrefs = False
    form_extra_fields = {
        'clan': SelectField('Clan',
            choices=[ (c.id, c.name) for c in models.Clan.query.all()])
    }
    column_list = ('name', 'pod', 'clan')

...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are need to use a **QuerySelectField**. For example:

```
from flask.ext.admin.form import Select2Widget

class MatrilineView(sqla.ModelView):
    column_hide_backrefs = False
    form_extra_fields = {
        'clan': sqla.fields.QuerySelectField(
            label='Clan',
            query_factory=lambda: Clan.query.all(),
            widget=Select2Widget()
        )
    }
    column_list = ('name', 'pod', 'clan')
```

Comment: Clan.query.all should be Clan.query.all() for it to work on flask-admin 1.4.0

Comment: your solution work fine for me , but I was use SelectField and added even onchange on it when I use this query Field it do the first part good load the query before get choices but its div element and have no values or change event any idea

Comment: How does this answer the question about dynamically changing the Select2 list of available pod options based on the clan selected? The pod AJAX query would need to be modified in JS on clan field "change" event, I think.